# how to call a method in a class into jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

i am trying to create a grading system in jsp. A total sum must be checked and a grade and remark will be given if it falls in a particular category. this is the method i wrote in my java class.

```
public void grade_adaptor(double sTotal,String Grade,String Remark){
 if(sTotal>=80){
            Grade="A";
            Remark="ADVANCE";
        }else if(sTotal>=75 && sTotal<=79.9){
            Grade="P";
            Remark="PROFICIENT";
        }else if(sTotal>=70 && sTotal<=74.9){
            Grade="AP";
            Remark="APPROACHING PROFICIENT";
        }else if(sTotal>=65 && sTotal<=69.9){
            Grade="D";
            Remark="DEVELOPING";
        }else if(sTotal>=0.0 && sTotal<=64.9){
            Grade="B";
            Remark="BEGINNING";
        }

 }
```

in my jsp page i have an input box which the value will be typed and i want to call the method to make that work. this is what i have:

```
<%@page import="pack.Grading" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="st.css" type="text/csss"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="update.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="t_value" value="total_value"/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/>
</form>

//this is the code i wrote below
<% 
String value=request.getParameter("t_value");
if(value!=null){
//these are the variables i created for the method in the java class
double total=Double.valueOf(value);
String t_grade,t_remark;

/*this is the code i wrote to call the method into the page.
the class in which the method is created is called Grading
*/
Grading gr=new Grading();
gr.grade_adaptor(total,t_grade,t_remark);
//a dialog box to display the result
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"value: "+total+" grade: "+t_grade+" remark:"+t_remark);
}
%>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but i get a null value for grade and remark in the JOptionPane. please what am i doing wrong. All help will be well appreciated.thank you

Comment: `Grading gr=new Grading` does this compile?

Comment: yes please it does. i get no error lines in the jsp page

Comment: Also, you may want to check the actual value you're passing to `grade_adaptor`. What happens if it receives, for example, 79.9999999?

Comment: will try and use DecimalFormat in the method and see if it works. will get back to you in a minute please

Comment: didnt work @FedericoklezCulloca because its even a single value typed in the input box. Eg. if i type in the value 80, i should get a result without the need for decimals. grade and remark must work with the value i type in the box. eg: 80.

Answer (score 0):

Core OOP are mismatched.
Method definition is faulty(or not used properly within goal):
 `public void grade_adaptor(double sTotal,String Grade,String Remark)`

Need only `sTotal` as calculation show.

Changes proposed:

```
class Result
{
    public String Grade;
    //or use getter
    String Remark;
    Result(String Grade,String Remark)
    {
        this.Grade = Grade;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

```
public Result grade_adaptor(double sTotal)
{
    if(sTotal>=80){
       return new Result("A","ADVANCE");
         ...  
}
```

```
Grading gr=new Grading();
Result r=gr.grade_adaptor(total);
//a dialog box to display the result
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"value: "+total+" grade: "+r.Grade+" remark:"+r.Remark);
```